# Detail object template in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I am customizing django admin and I would like to have some template of an object's detail. Just like the "edit" template but without editable fields.

In CRUD philosophy the Read web page.

Is there any snippet, package or some advice about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Anentropic for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31876991/714305)

I had to create a DetailView, I let my code here for future visitors:

```
class UsersDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Users
    template_name = 'users_detail.html'
```

It is very minimalist.

You can also add the model parameter in `urls.py` so the view can be generic. Like this:

```
from app_name.models import GenericDetailView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^proj/app_name/(?P<object_name>users)/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/detail$', GenericDetailView.as_view(model=Users)),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly in the standard Django admin

But if you define the [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method on your model you will get a "View on site" button in the admin

So this is a mechanism you can use to provide your own view (eg [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)) for the 'Read'